# Does the security version and vendor of the JDK affect deployment?

Tags: java, java-17, adoptopenjdk, corretto, redhat-openjdk

I have a jar that was compiled using Amazon Corretto 17.0.9.8.1.
Can I deploy it using any vendor's 17.0.x java binary?
Or do I have to use a binary from the same vendor with the same security version to deploy it without issues?

Comment: Why not just try it? I'd expect it to work, or someone really shouldn't call their compiler "java compiler" or JVM. Also note that Maven repositories only keep one instance of each jar around, not one for each JVM vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any app built with a JDK that complies with a particular version of the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) will run on any other JDK/JRE implementing the same version.

And likely later versions as well, with rare exceptions.

So, for example, you could build your app using [*Amazon Corretto*](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc) 17.0.x, then run that app on [*Eclipse Adoptium Temurin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoptium#Eclipse_Temurin) 17.0.x. And some other user could run with [*Azul Systems Zulu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems#Azul_Platform_Core_(Formerly_Zulu_and_Zulu_Embedded_JVM)) 17.0.x.

You may choose to obtain a JDK from vendors including BellSoft, Adoptium, Amazon, SAP, Oracle, IBM, Red Hat, Microsoft, and more. Be sure to study the terms of each product.

If building a JavaFX app, you may want to use a JDK/JRE bundled with the OpenJFX libraries. At least two vendors provide such an edition of their products: *Azul Systems* and *BellSoft*.

You may choose to bundle a JVM with your app. See the *jlink* and *jpackage* tooling to assist you.